# Bootstrap grid with min-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement 2 responsive divs but one with a min-width but can't figure out how:

Here is the gist of the idea:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2"
        style="min-width:227px"></div>
   <div class="col-lg-10"
        style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want a 2:10 ratio between the two divs, but cap the left div to a min of 227px. When it goes below that, I want to collapse the two divs (allow them to overlap) but make the right div float to the right side.

However, I can't get the right div to float to the right no matter what I've tried. It always "goes under" the left div once the min-width is reached.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Brother I am new in this community, so any mistake please ignore it**

U can achieve this functionality with custom CSS code in this code u can get the 2:10 ratio of when the screen size is greater than 1362px when 1362px screen width reach than then the min-width of first div active i.e. 227px and the second div adjust accordingly and when the screen size goes to 768px then both the div display inline

**if you have any doubt then please tell me**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <style>
        *{
            margin:0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .outer-section{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .col_custom_2{
            min-width: 227px;
            width: 16.66%;
            float: left;
        }
        .col_custom_10{
            width: calc(100% - 16.66%);
            float: right;
        }
        @media (max-width: 1363px) {
            .col_custom_10{
                width: calc(100% - 227px);
            }
        }
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .col_custom_2,.col_custom_10{
                min-width: 100%;
            }
        }


    </style>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<section class="outer-section">
    <div class="col_custom_2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit quisquam, voluptatem quaerat ex. Aperiam maxime labore cumque, quidem cupiditate eum inventore dolorem deserunt perspiciatis consequuntur?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_custom_10">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe cum repellat dolor magnam at est veniam, ex rem odio necessitatibus molestias vel dolorum numquam voluptas, odit, nemo autem, porro alias. Expedita, voluptate repudiandae officiis corporis explicabo iusto vero saepe laborum possimus dolore temporibus quasi quas numquam quibusdam fugiat dolorem, deleniti?</p>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This is what I have now, but when the min-width is reached, the col-lg-10 div goes "under" the col-lg-2 div and bot aligns from the left side of the page. I'm fine with overlap, but I want col-lg-10 to align from the ride side if possible.